# Grab, move and drop control in Form by mouse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello I have found this code that might help me with following issue, I'm trying to make drag, drop and move label in my Form by mouse.

```
 private Point MouseDownLocation;

    private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

But when I assing mousemove and mousedown as events to label and i try to grab the label and move with mouse it moves with the whole Form.

May I ask where is should the code be improved?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `this.Left` (which is the form), you need to move your control:

```
private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MyControl.Left = e.X + MyControl.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        MyControl.Top = e.Y + MyControl.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

In addition, you may want to capture the mouse on button down, and release it on button up.  That will prevent very fast movements from "breaking" your logic.  For details, see [Mouse Capture in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545.aspx).